# Python to Android using buildozer 'Error compiling Cython' file

Tags: android, python-3.x, cython

I am trying to convert a python pygame to android with Buildozer, following some guided instruction...i encounter different error, which i could solve, however, i have the following one where i don't know hoe to fix it....help !!!

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import sys
import traceback

include "jnius_compat.pxi"
include "jni.pxi"
include "config.pxi"
^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius.pyx:100:0: 'config.pxi' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------

include "jnius_compat.pxi"
include "jni.pxi"
inc`lude "config.pxi"

IF JNIUS_PLATFORM == "android":
  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius.pyx:102:3: Compile-time name 'JNIUS_PLATFORM' not defined

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
include "jni.pxi"
include "config.pxi"

IF JNIUS_PLATFORM == "android":
include "jnius_jvm_android.pxi"
ELIF JNIUS_PLATFORM == "win32":
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

jnius/jnius.pyx:104:5: Compile-time name 'JNIUS_PLATFORM' not defined

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
include "config.pxi"
^
------------------------------------------------------------`
jnius/jnius_jvm_dlopen.pxi:1:0: 'config.pxi' not found
```

i try to update and install different verison of cython and update JDK version, but still not     working.
depende of which version of Cython i use newer of older i get this message as well.

jnius/jnius.pyx:100:0: 'config.pxi' not found
warning: jnius/jnius.pyx:102:0: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310

Anyone know how to solve this....thanks

Comment: I suspect the basic problem is "`config.pxi` not found". Does this file exist? Is there a step in the build process to generate this file that you've missed? I doubt if Cython or JDK version is relevant here.

Comment: Maybe a step in setup.py: https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/blob/dce5ce0f3ec35eef288a2a53fd3f7db0f6c598d2/setup.py#L87-L96